# is there a way to read cookie in constructor in web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to read cookie named as `key` from browser in constructor in web API but it is throwing error shown below. Is there any possible way ?

code:

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["key"];
```

[System.NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws0Lj.png)

Comment: What class is it? A controller? A filter? Why do you want to read it in the constructor? Controllers are instantiated on a request, and then the properties are set - therefore you don't have request data in the constructor.

Comment: It is a controller. I am storing a value in cookie and want to use that value in my constructor for initialization.

Comment: Request is null at this point, as ckuri said. What would you do exactly with cookie value after you get it. Maybe we can help with workaround.

Comment: i have two different connection strings and i want to configure them based on the value which i have stored in cookie and I want to do it in constructor itself

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This isn't going to work inside of a constructor. How could it? You receive requests in controller actions. There is no request in the constructor.

You should be able to do (inside an Action):

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["key"];
if(cookieValue != null) 
{ 
    //...
}
```

I suspect that something else is triggering the null exception because simply accessing `Request.Cookies["key"]` shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: This is not correct, as Request is null in Web API Constructor.

Comment: I missed "Constructor". Anyways, if he wants to put the code in the correct place (action),  both mine and your deleted answer will work.